# Where is the problem in this prototype [ajax.Request] code?

Tags: javascript, forms, post, prototypejs, ajax.request

```
  function sendM() {
new Ajax.Request("sendm.html", 
{ 
method: 'post', 
postBody: 'text='+ $F('text') +'&sub='+ $F('subject') +'&sname='+ $F('name') +'&sfmail='+ $F('email') +'to='+ $F('to'),
onLoading:showLoad,    
onComplete: showResponse
});
}
function showLoad(){
    $('dresult').innerHTML= "מבצע את הפעולה &nbsp;&nbsp;<br /><br />";
}

function showResponse(req){
    $('dresult').innerHTML= req.responseText;
}
```

The hTML Form code :

```
<form id="sfunc" name="sfunc" onsubmit="return false;">
```

שם
            
             
        
        
            דוא"ל
            
             
        
        
            יעד
            
            
            1
            2
            3
            
            
        
        
            נושא
            
             
        
        
            הודעה

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?  Or are you just trying to quiz us for fun?

Comment: No proper information about your problem won't fetch you any answer.

Comment: this is the problem that i did not get neither error nor code work , i have like this code that send messages page which is sendm.html , the code of sendm.html is in this link , it's txt file .http://www.ebncana.com/personal/mail.txt

Answer (score -1):

You attempted to use showLoad and showResponse before they were initialized. Move your function definitions for showLoad and showResponse above your Ajax request.

For future reference, note that any error occuring inside your Ajax handlers do not print out errors in your browser error console. You'll have to create breakpoints in the handlers to fix the problem. Use a debugger like Firefox's Firebug plugin.

Comment: Sorry but this  is completely wrong. See: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#functions-and-statements